# Mink Fail to execute JavaScript

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, mink

I'm trying to click on element with using JS script to avoid "other element would receive click" error. Here is my code:

```
$drive = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$element = $drive->find('css', 'input[value^="Enregistrer et C"]');
$this->getSession()->executeScript("arguments[0].click();", $element);
```

As a result I ger following error:

```
unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
      (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="layout-region layout-region-node-footer">

  <div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">

    <div class="dropbutton-wrapper dropbutton-multiple">
      <div class="dropbutton-widget">
        <ul data-drupal-selector="edit-save" class="dropbutton">
          <li class="moderation-state-draft dropbutton-action">
            <input type="submit" name="op" value="Enregistrer et Créer un nouveau brouillon" class="button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit"></li>
```

Update:
The required element is not visilble on the page and I need to scroll down to get it visible, from the other hand there are several elements on top of it, so simple selenium clicking would return "Other element would receive click" error. So I decied to use JS scipt to click on element:

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and the webelement identified as `'css', 'input[value^="xxxx"]'` ?

Comment: I've updated question with screenshot -> link "HMTL Code "

Comment: How about `xxxx` in `value^="xxxx"` ?

Comment: Updated locator

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the *WebElement* have a *class* attribute as `button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit`. So you can be more granular and change the line :

```
$element = $drive->find('css', 'input[value^="Enregistrer et C"]');
```

To :

```
$element = $drive->find('css', 'input.button.button--primary.js-form-submit.form-submit[name="op"][value^="Enregistrer et C"]');
```

> **Note** : As the *class* attribute contains `js-form-submit` so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *webelement* to render within the *HTML DOM* before finding it.

Comment: Can you share the formatted text based _HTML_ for analysis?

Comment: Please have a look now

Comment: Besides a I can say that the required button is not visible on the page while clicking. You need to scroll downt if to click in a regular way. But I think JS script "clicking" execution should resolve this prioblem

Comment: The `<input>` element is within a `<li>` tag which is within a `<ul>`. Ideally you should first invoke the `click()` on the element which expands all the `<li>` elements, next you have to access the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

following JS  function helped to me:

```
public function clickJS ($element){
    $jsclick = <<<JS
        function getElementByXpath(path) {
            return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    }
    getElementByXpath('$element').click();
JS;
    try {
        $this->getSession()->executeScript($jsclick);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e);
    }
}
```